# Keeping the minimum row value across multiple columns and the value of closest neighboring column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

Given the example table

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[8,4,8,4,9],'Ap':[0.001,0.06,0.001,0.1,0.002],'B':[7,3,9,3,6],
                  'Bp':[0.005,0.006,0.01,0.007,0.06],'C':[4,1,4,8,9],
                  'Cp':[0.004,0.008,0.2,0.006,0.00001]}, index=['x','y','z','zz','yz'])
```

That looks like this:

```
    A     Ap    B   Bp      C   Cp
x   8   0.001   7   0.005   4   0.00400
y   4   0.060   3   0.006   1   0.00800
z   8   0.001   9   0.010   4   0.20000
zz  4   0.100   3   0.007   8   0.00600
yz  9   0.002   6   0.060   9   0.00001
```

I'd like the keep/record the row value for the column with the lowest value from (A,B,C)

```
new = pd.DataFrame()
new['Minimum'] = df[[df.columns[0],df.columns[2],df.columns[4]]].min(axis=1)
```

This result will look like this

```
    Minimum
x   4
y   1
z   4
zz  3
yz  6
```

But I'd also like to record the pval associated with the minimum value kept (Ap, Bp, Cp) and I'm unsure how to accomplish that.

So for example the final result should look like this

```
    Minimum pVal
x   4       0.004
y   1       0.008
z   4       0.200
zz  3       0.007
yz  6       0.060
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets use `idxmin` to get the column names corresponding to min values then use advance indexing with numpy to get the corresponding min values

```
c = ['A', 'B', 'C']
x, y = range(len(df)), df[c].idxmin(1)

df['min'] = df.values[x, df.columns.get_indexer_for(y)]
df['pVal'] = df.values[x, df.columns.get_indexer_for(y + 'p')]
```

##### Result

```
    A     Ap  B     Bp  C       Cp  min   pVal
x   8  0.001  7  0.005  4  0.00400  4.0  0.004
y   4  0.060  3  0.006  1  0.00800  1.0  0.008
z   8  0.001  9  0.010  4  0.20000  4.0  0.200
zz  4  0.100  3  0.007  8  0.00600  3.0  0.007
yz  9  0.002  6  0.060  9  0.00001  6.0  0.060
```

###### Some details

- `idxmin(1)`: returns the name of column corresponding to min value for each row
- `df.columns.get_indexer_for` returns the numerical indices(zero based) which can then be used to access the corresponding columns

Comment: TY. pandas.Index.get_indexer_for was exactly what I needed